# Multiline text with codeception

Tags: php, codeception

I'm a bit new to PHP and codeception and I'm struggling with something that should not be too hard. I have some data that I want to enter into a textarea as shown in the format below

```
Email  FirstName  LastName

test@gmail.com  test user

test2@gmail.com  test2 user2
```

I have tried

```
    $I->fillField(['name' => 'data'], 'Email  FirstName  LastName');
    $I->fillField(['name' => 'data'], 'test@gmail.com  test  user');
```

,

```
   $I->fillField(['name' => 'data'], 'Email  FirstName  LastName');
   $I->pressKey('#data',WebDriverKeys::ENTER);
   $I->fillField(['name' => 'data'], 'test@gmail.com  test  user');
```

and a few other combinations which have failed. The docs do not explicitly have a `newline` command from what I have seen (ofcourse `\n` won't work). Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried \n with double quotes?
`$I->fillField(['name' => 'data'], "Email\nFirstName\nLastName");

Comment: Wow no I hadn't tried double quotes, thanks :). Guess my `\n` not working was total rubbish